# PartCopy or bochs configuration failing in windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: operating-system, bootloader, bochs, vfd

I am trying to create a bootloader [following this link](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev3.html) the things i did are

1. create a vfd as per given and formatted it.
2. used partcopy `partcopy Boot1.bin 0 200 -f0`
3. then created a config file for bochs emulator.

while `bochs` emulator loading it is asking for config file when i provide it, emulator  stops saying `panic`

And i also want to know how to know if partcopy is has copied data into floppy. As i try to open the floppy drive after the copy it says format to use( i presume the problem is partcopy only ) .

how can i fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in configuration file of the bochs.

```
romimage:    file=BIOS-bochs-legacy, address=0xf0000
vgaromimage: file=VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
```

keep the  rom image and vgaromimage in the same place as configuration file. it will work fine .